# Hidden pins in Proteus

Tags: frequency, schematics, logic-gates, counter, proteus

I'm implementing the following scheme and I have trouble with **IC4** element **(7430: 8-pin NAND)** that have 7 and 14 pins, as I understand, **VCC** and **GROUND** respectively. But in Proteus 8 NAND don't have these pins. Also on **IC[1-3]** pins +V are missing. What should I do?
[image: Frequency Divider]

[image]

Comment: what about the 7490? ... why are you not asking about them? ... does the simulation work without the power connections?

Comment: You know, yes, 7490 too. In general, some elements in the scheme have pins that aren't in Proteus.

Comment: Does it mean that the scheme should be revised?

Comment: what do you mean by `revised`?

Comment: When I said that the scheme should be revised, I meant that the schematic should propably be updated to reflect the actual pinouts of the ICs.

Comment: what does that mean? ... aren't the pin numbers accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fortunately a very simple task. By default, the GND and VCC pins are connected to the GND and VCC net. If you haven't changed them, VCC will be defaulted to 5V.

To change them, right click the component and select properties. You can then select "hidden Pins". This will be an option for any IC where pins are hidden.

[image]

Once you have done that, you can select the nets for them to be connected to.

[image]

Simply select the net you want the power rails connected to. Make sure you have set your nets up before.